# Append data to CSV Python

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

I am trying to append some data to a CSV file. I have the following code

```
financial_ratios_annually = fa.financial_ratios(ticker, api_key, period="annual")
all_data = [financial_ratios_annually]

print(financial_ratios_annually)

with open('testing.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for row in all_data:
        spamwriter.writerow(row)
```

This prints out the financial data to the terminal okay, but when I check the CSV file that is created, it is only printing out the first row, a row of dates and nothing else is getting put into the CSV file.

Thanks

Now when I run the code i get the following error: ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

The functions from the library must be using pandas, but I wasn't getting this error at all until just now.

Comment: I believe its supposed to be `spamwriter.writerow([row])`. Also are you checking what `row` contains?

Comment: `all_data = [financial_ratios_annually]`. This defines `all_data` as a list with one element. What is the intent? If `financial_ratios_annually` is your list of rows, iterate over that.

Comment: @hmm I'm not that familiar with Python so just copied some code from a previous script I managed to write, I will try it.